# Get domainname from string via regular expression

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm trying to get the domain name from a string. From this URL http://www.tvstore.nl/product/572875/samsung-ue48ju7500.html

I'd like to get `www.tvstore.nl` as a result. However, with this function I just get `www.tvstore`. What am I missing? I want this to work for any TLD, whether that's .com, .org, .de, .co etc.

```
Protected Function ExtractDomainFromURL(ByVal sURL As String) As String
    Dim rg As New Regex("://(?<host>([a-z\d][-a-z\d]*[a-z\d]\.)*[a-z][-a-z\d]+[a-z])")
    If rg.IsMatch(sURL) Then
        Return rg.Match(sURL).Result("${host}")
    Else
        Return String.Empty
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:\/\/(?<host>([a-z\d][-a-z\d]*[a-z\d]\.)*[a-z][-a-z\d]*[a-z])

                                                     ^^
```

Just change the quantifier from `+` to `*`.As you have used `+` it is expecting a `3` letter word ,whereas you have only `2` i.e `nl`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/iV6mP5/3